# use invoke command with credentials stored from array

Tags: powershell

Good day

Please assist with the following. I'm still in my beginnings with Powershell. I have a script that needs to install software on users machine with no admin rights. I created an array of credentials for local admin that will be used with invoke-command to start the process of installing. I seem to not get it right as it does not run it goes straight to catch. please have a look at my code below and advice. Any help will be much appreciated.
when testing only with out try catch, i get the error:Invoke-Command : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Credential'. userName

Howerver. when i check the value of eg. $local_cred[3] i get the correct output shoing that is ps credential
[image]

```
  #create PScredential for all credentials
   $c_user = @("IT", "Power")
   $old_pass_IT = (Get-Content C:\Ninja\cred.txt)[0] | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
   $local_pass_old_IT = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $c_user[0], $old_pass_IT 
   $old_pass_P = (Get-Content C:\Ninja\cred.txt)[1] | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
   $local_pass_old_P = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $c_user[1], $old_pass_P
   $new_pass_IT= (Get-Content C:\Ninja\cred.txt)[2] | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
   $local_pass_new_IT = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $c_user[0], $new_pass_IT 
   $new_pass_P= (Get-Content C:\Ninja\cred.txt)[3] | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
   $local_pass_new_P = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $c_user[1], $new_pass_P 
   $local_cred = @($local_pass_old_IT,$local_pass_old_P,$local_pass_new_IT,$local_pass_new_P)


#function to install with all different credentials
Function install_ninja(){
    

    Invoke-Command   -Credential $local_cred -ScriptBlock {
        #run setup file
        Start-Process "C:\Ninja\NinjaInstaller.msi" -ArgumentList "/q" -Wait 
    }
}


#Check if the file has been downlaoded successfully
#$successful_download_path = Test-Path -Path $destinationsetupfile -PathType Leaf -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$successful_download = "C:\Ninja\NinjaInstaller.msi"
[string]$verified_download =(Get-Item $successful_download).length/1MB
[int]$Verified_correct = [int]$verified_download
$original_file = "33.87891"
[int]$exact_file =[int]$original_file

#check if the file has been downloaded successfully. 
if( $Verified_correct -eq $exact_file){


    
    #install software by calling the function install_ninja and put credentials from the array($local
    
        try {
            install_ninja($local_cred[0]) -ErrorAction Stop
        }
        catch{
        write-host "fail1"
        }
   
        #Power old
        try {
            install_ninja($local_cred[1]) -ErrorAction Stop
        }
        catch{
        write-host "fail2"
        }
    
        try {
            install_ninja($local_cred[2]) -ErrorAction Stop
        }
        catch{
        write-host "fail3"
        }
   
        try {
            install_ninja($local_cred[3]) -ErrorAction Stop
        }
        catch{
        write-host "fail4"
        }
    }
    else{
        Write-host " Software was not downlaoded succesfully. Please make sure you have internet and try again"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're passing `$local_cred`'s children to `install_ninja()`, you probably want:

```
Function install_ninja(){
    

    Invoke-Command   -Credential $args -ScriptBlock {
        #run setup file
        Start-Process "C:\Ninja\NinjaInstaller.msi" -ArgumentList "/q" -Wait 
    }
}
```

Also, if you're trying to start a process with elevated privileges, you may also need to use [`Start-Process` with `-Verb RunAs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-7.2#example-5--start-powershell-as-an-administrator).